# javascript remove only value but remain the key

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I have a json object

`var myObj = {'test' : {'key1' : 'value', 'key2': 'value', 'key3': 'value'}}`

How can I run a loop to only remove the value but remain the key
so that I get this

`var myObj = {'test' : {'key1' : '', 'key2': '', 'key3': ''}}`

Or how can i make a copy of the Object without the value??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can loop through properties of a javascript object like this:

```
for (var prop in myObj) {
    if (myObj.hasOwnProperty(prop) &&
        typeof myObj[prop] !== 'function') {

        myObj[prop] = '';
    }
}
```

Quick rundown of what this does and why:

- `for (var prop in myObj)` will go over every property in your object.
- `if (myObj.hasOwnProperty(prop)` will make sure you don't change properties inherited through the prototype chain (we don't *usually* want to do that).
- `&& typeof myObj[prop] !== 'function')` will ignore any property that is a function. If you do want to change the value of functions on your object, this check should be removed.
- `myObj[prop] = ''` assigns a new value to the property (an empty string, in this case).

To do this check "in depth" (multiple levels deep), you would have to call this recursively:

```js
var myObj = {
  'test': {
    'key1': 'value',
    'key2': 'value',
    'key3': 'value',
    'key4': { 'subkey1': 'value', 'subkey2': 'value' }
  }
}

var replaceProps = function(obj, replaceWith) {
  for (var prop in obj) {
    if (obj.hasOwnProperty(prop) && typeof obj[prop] !== 'function') {

      if (typeof obj[prop] === 'object') {
        replaceProps(obj[prop], replaceWith)
      } else {
        obj[prop] = replaceWith;
      }
    }
  }
}

replaceProps(myObj, '');

console.log(myObj);
```

Answer (score 2):

You could iterate the keys and assign an empty string

```js
var myObj = {'test' : {'key1' : 'value', 'key2': 'value', 'key3': 'value'}};

Object.keys(myObj.test).forEach(function (k) {
    myObj.test[k] = '';
});
console.log(myObj);
```

Answer (score 0):

`for-in` loop, and replacing the value with a blank. Or a combination of `Object.keys` and `array.reduce`.